# How to let json4s or other scala json libs generate Java Collections

Tags: java, json, scala, json4s

Background:

1. I use some Java libs which require Java Collections (java.util.ArrayList etc.)
2. Input JSON items are dynamic, so I can only use `Map[String, Any]` as the result type to json4s' extract method (viz. `parse(json).extract[Map[String, Any]]`)

Exception:

I got an exception from Java libs says `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`

Reason:

I guess it is because Json4s just generates scala `List` but Java `List` for `JArray` elements (e.g. `["a", "b", "c"]` => `scala.collection.immutable.List("a", "b", "c")`)

So, the question is how I can handle the case?

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the scala types for json4s (and in general for all scala code). Then you can use [scala.collection.JavaConverters](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) to convert the scala object in the following way.

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
val javaList: java.util.List[Int] = list.asJava

yourJavaLib.call(javaList)
```

In case that you really need an ArrayList (and not only a `java.util.List`) I would just create it in the following way.

```
val arrayList = new ArrayList(javaList)
```

Comment: According to the background, I don't know `Map` values's type. So should I loop the whole `Map` and convert all the scala List to java list?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I found an ugly but effective way for the case.

`mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`
`mapper.readValue(org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write(scalaMap), new TypeReference[java.util.Map[String, Object]](){})`